# Firebase revokeRefreshTokens in backend server then firebase.auth().signOut() then try to login (google provider)

Tags: java, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase for authentication using firebaseui-web.
Following is the issue use case :

1. The user login via firebaseui successfully
2. The token is validated in backend server: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken)
3. The user press logout button
4. The backend revokes the refresh token in order to invalidate the token (Im I wrong?!) : FirebaseAuth.getInstance().revokeRefreshTokens(decodedToken.getUid());
5. The user tries to reauthenticate, the firebaseui is displayed but when the client press immediateley the "sign in with google" button an error message is shown: "Please login again to perform this operation  Dismiss"; Apparently google server telss that the token is expired (400)
6. After some seconds the user retries to authenticate and it works.

Can you help me please resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you think there's a bug with Firebase UI, then file an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web

Comment: I don't think it is related to firebase-ui but firebase, because the same behaviour is noticed when using:var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider),

Comment: Any one has a solution for this issue please?